# How to setup SQL ALchemy in a Flask project properly?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have a flask project in which I want to have a db connection to my Postgrsql db.
I've looked around online and I've seen that for initializing the connection you simply instantiate a SQLAlchemy object inside your app.py file by passing the Flask Application object

```
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

then you can declare every model you want by making it extending the Model class defined in the db object

```
class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

I think it's quite a mess because if I want to separate my models in different files I have to reference the 'db' instance around my code by importing directly from the app.py file (having then circular references)

All the tutorials online put everything inside the app.py file and it's than importing directly from the app.py file

Is there a way to initialize SQLAlchemy in a cleaner way, by separating all the models under different folders and maybe without a direct reference to the app.py?

Thanks

Comment: Look into "blueprints". An example is the SO python community site [here](https://github.com/sopython/sopython-site) that you can work towards (it's primarily written by the principal maintainer of Flask). One thing to note is that `flask-sqlalchemy` models will only work in, well, flask. There are other ways to get _general_ SQLA models working in any context, but that's a bit of effort that you might not need

Comment: More specifically, the Flask Mega Tutorial (https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world) will walk you through how to use blueprints and blueprint-specific models.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate SQLAlchemy initialization and models, then import what you need inside app.py. With the below setup you wouldn't need to import db from app.py, avoiding circular reference.

```
.
├── database
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── models.py
└── app.py
```

In config.py you can import `Flask` and `SQLAlchemy` and initialize the app and database:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'your_database_info'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Then in models (you can also create separate model files for each database tables) import `db` from `config.py`:

```
from database.config import db

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

Finally, import both `app`, `db`, and your database models in `app.py`:

```
from database.models import User #import other database models
from database.config import app, db

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```